# Looking for a QGIS tutorial

Tags: qgis, qt, references

I am looking for QGIS tutorials that cover the topics of making a user interface to update the attribute table or any related tutorial that might help.  Does anyone know of one?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: If you are looking for Tutorials have a look [here](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/).

Comment: Maybe this? http://manual.linfiniti.com/en/create_vector_data/forms.html but is for fill the attributes by the time you are creating a new polygon. or Maybe you are looking for a tutorial of the field calculator?

Comment: Qt Designer https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LYF0spYkXUs easy to follow (from a non programmer)

Comment: thank you @Hombydd I have already done all of these tutorials.  They are excellent, and extremely valuable!

Comment: Thank you @Mapperz, this is the program I was leaning toward using this helps a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [QGIS User Guide](http://docs.qgis.org/2.8/pdf/en/QGIS-2.8-UserGuide-en.pdf)
.

At the pages 129-130 (in the section 12.5.8 Working with the Attribute Table), you'll find all the user interface buttons you need to update the attribute table.

If you want to update the Attribute Table with Expressions, you'll find a complete list starting at page 110 (section 12.4 Expressions).

Comment: seems to be more of a comment than an answer, please explain why this is good user guide.